# Add a confirmation modal on a custom action

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig, sonata-admin

I've followed this tutorial on how to add a custom action to my entities.

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/cookbook/recipe_custom_action.html

It works perfectly without any issues.

But now I want to add a confirmation modal on that action so that you can't just execute it, but first after a confirmation asking whether you are sure you want to do it.

What I did was just making the link a data toggle and removing the actual action route. Add a bootstrap div class for the modal and in there add a link with the route. But what happens now is that the id of the very first entity is used for all entities and not their ids respectively.

I changed this:

```
{% if admin.isGranted('EDIT', object) and admin.hasRoute('delOnt') %}
    <a href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('delOnt', object) }}"
       class="btn btn-sm btn-default edit_link">
        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        {{ 'action_del_ont' | trans({}, "QiOpticksBundle") }}
    </a>
{% endif %}
```

to this:

```
{% if admin.isGranted('EDIT', object) and admin.hasRoute('delOnt') %}
    <a href="#"
       class="btn btn-sm btn-default edit_link"
       data-toggle="modal"
       data-target="#deleteModal">
        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        {{ 'action_del_ont' | trans({}, "QiOpticksBundle") }}
    </a>

    <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete ONT</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Are you sure you want to delete this ONT?
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                        {{ 'no' | trans({}, "QiOpticksBundle") }}
                    </button>
                    <a href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('delOnt', object) }}"
                       class="btn btn-danger"
                       title="{{ 'action_del_ont'|trans({}, 'QiOpticksBundle') }}">
                        {{ 'action_del_ont' | trans({}, "QiOpticksBundle") }}
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

and now all entities' actions make use of the first entity's id, and not their own.

I've tried to replace `{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('delOnt', object) }}` with the actual root name, like this `{{ path('admin_qi_opticks_tl1ont_delOnt', {'id': object.id}) }}`, but it result in the same problem. Are there any way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. This was one small silly mistake.

All the modals for all buttons are correct. The route inside the modal is also correct. The problem was that all the links opened the same - very first - modal, because all the id's in the links referred to the same modal to open.

Inside each link, the `data-target` should be unique to open its unique modal, therefore I changed the value of `data-target` to `"#deleteModal-{{ object.id }}"`. Now each link looks for the correct modal. And then you do the same with the ids of each modal. `id="deleteModal-{{ object.id }}"`.

Thus my code looks like this:

```
{% if admin.isGranted('EDIT', object) and admin.hasRoute('delOnt') %}
    <a href="#"
       class="btn btn-sm btn-default edit_link"
       data-toggle="modal"
       data-target="#deleteModal-{{ object.id }}">
        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        {{ 'action_del_ont' | trans({}, "QiOpticksBundle") }}
    </a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal-{{ object.id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete ONT</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Are you sure you want to delete this ONT?
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                        {{ 'no' | trans({}, "QiOpticksBundle") }}
                    </button>
                    <a href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('delOnt', object) }}"
                       class="btn btn-danger"
                       title="{{ 'action_del_ont'|trans({}, 'QiOpticksBundle') }}">
                        {{ 'action_del_ont' | trans({}, "QiOpticksBundle") }}
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```